# The bound of the cardinalities of the sets that are subsets of their power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the set $A_0=\{\emptyset\}$. The power set of $A_0$ is $P(A_0)=\{\emptyset,A_0\}$. Hence $A_0\subseteq P(A_0)$. I can also define inductively $A_n=A_{n-1}\cup \{\{\{...\{\emptyset\}...\}\}\}$. I guess I cannot use this construction to get an infinite set $A$ with $A\subseteq P(A)$. Is there an infinite set with this property? Is there a bound for the cardinalities of such sets?

Comment: Of course you right, I edited. Thanks! I am confused with the brackets.

Comment: A set $A$ such that $A\subseteq P(A)$ is called a *transitive* set. Note that the union of any family of transitive sets is transitive. So, if you have a transitive set of size $n$ for each finite $n,$ the union of those sets will be an infinite transitive set. Also, if $A$ is transitive, then $P(A)$ is transitive. So you can get uncountable transitive sets, and in fact transitive sets of any size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no bound to the possible size of such sets. In fact, the [von Neumann cumulative hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe) is a proper class of such sets, with arbitarily large cardinalities, which is constructed in a similar way to how you did it (or, at least, attempted to do it). They are defined as follows.

- Let $V_0 = \varnothing$;
- If $V_{\alpha}$ has been defined, let $V_{\alpha+1} = \mathcal{P}(V_{\alpha})$;
- If $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal and $V_{\alpha}$ has been defined for all $\alpha < \lambda$, then define $V_{\lambda} = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} V_{\alpha}$.

You can verify that $V_{\alpha} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(V_{\alpha}) = V_{\alpha+1}$ for all ordinals $\alpha$.

More generally, any [transitive set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set) $X$ satisfies $X \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$. What it means for $X$ to be transitive is that, for all $x \in X$, if $y \in x$ then $y \in X$. This is the same as saying that $x \in X \Rightarrow x \subseteq X$. But $x \subseteq X$ means the same thing as $x \in \mathcal{P}(X)$, so a set $X$ is transitive if and only if $X \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$.

Comment: It is sad I forgot about transitive sets. Thanks for your answer.